# Pointwise a.e. Convergence of Fourier Series in $L^p$ Space?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series, lp-spaces

Does the Fourier Series of functions in ${L^p}$(T) converge pointwise a.e. to the functions themselves (T here is [-$\pi, \pi$] with 2$\pi$ periodicity)? I know in $L^2$(T) the functions $e^{inx}$ for integer n forms an orthonormal basis of $L^2$(T), so every $L^2$ function has a convergent Fourier Series equal to itself, but not sure about the general $L^p$ case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the exponentials are an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ does not at all directly imply anything about *pointwise* convergence, only $L^2$ convergence. But, as @uniquesolution notes, L. Carleson proved that in fact the Fourier series of $L^2$ functions *do* converge pointwise almost everywhere. Then R. Hunt proved (just a few years later) the corresponding pointwise a.e. result for $L^p$ functions.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I thought Parseval proved something about if E is an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space H, then all f in H can be written as an orthonormal convergent sum of a_n * e_n, where a_n = <f, e_n> and  e_n is in E. Does this imply that Fourier Series converge pointwise a.e. in L^2?

Thanks for providing the reference to Carleson and Hunt theorems - they were exactly what I needed!

Comment: @SimonLi, Parseval's theorem says nothing at all (directly) about pointwise convergence. It gives convergence in the $L^2$ metric, which, again, does not directly mention "pointwise" at all. Oppositely, pointwise convergence (without further conditions) says nothing directly about $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: ... but I should add that the proof that $L^2$ is _complete_ shows that a Cauchy subsequence in the $L^2$ topology has a _subsequence_ converging a.e. pointwise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. It is a very deep theorem due to Carleson. It was probably the most difficult open question about Fourier Series, until Carleson settled it in around $1966$, if I am not mistaken.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson's_theorem